# How to solve ValueError is not in List? It's in the list

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How to solve ValueError is not in List problem? I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

```
  from urllib.request import urlopen
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  html = urlopen("http://uk.reuters.com/business/quotes/financialHighlights?   symbol=AAPL.O")

  bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
  tag = bsObj.findAll("td")
  tagList = []
  for tagItem in tag:
      tagList.append(tagItem)

  print(tagList.index("<td>Dec</td>"))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/home/Desktop/development/x/code.py", line 11, in <module>
print(tagList.index("<td>Dec</td>"))
ValueError: '<td>Dec</td>' is not in list

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `for tag in tag:` is confusing.

Comment: OK, i will update the code to replace tag with tagItem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a list of `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` objects. Their string representation seems to match the string you're looking for, except that objects are not equal since they have different types.

(note that printing the list yields `[<td>Dec</td>, <td>Dec</td>]`, note the absence of quotes, printing the same list but with strings yields `['<td>Dec</td>', '<td>Dec</td>']`)

Quickfix: create your list as string

```
for tagItem in tag:
  tagList.append(str(tagItem))
```

or as list comprehension:

```
tagList = [str(tagItem) for tagItem in tag]
```

Now `index` works: returns "0"

Note that you could keep your list unconverted (if you want to keep the objects, not coerce to strings), and use the following to find the first index compared to a string:

```
print(next(i for i,x in enumerate(tagList) if str(x)=="<td>Dec</td>"))
```